# Have a custom Setter on property for EF Code First model entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to override or add code to setter of property for entity model object in EF Code First approach.

e.g.

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle
    {
        get;
        set { // eg. proper case the job title }
    }

}
```

I had tried having a public property marked NotMapped and this set/get to private/protected property that is.  But it seems that the property has to public to be created in table.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write the logic in there if you want, just transform the property into a non-automatic one and perform the checks as you would do with a normal property.

```
 private string jobTitle;
 public string JobTitle
 {
      get { return jobTitle; }
      set
      {
           // do your fancy stuff or just jobTitle = value
      }
 }
```

Remember that if you change the value from db inside your setter it will probably be saved that way later on after you perform `SaveChanges()` on the context.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You can ignore the propertie using the `ModelBuilder` and `.Ignore(...)`

> **.Ignore(...)** Excludes a property from the model so that it will not be mapped to the database.

#### Sample

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    // other DbSet's

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Ignore(x => x.JobTitle);
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [EF Features: Fluent API Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I did something slightly different.
In your example I would change the mapping file so that the getter and setter on the property that is mapped to the database to be private and lowercase just as dmusial showed. Then I created a property that was NOT mapped in the edmx file as show here (Note: While I usually would make member fields _jobTitle, I'm using the code generation and starting with an _ is not allowed in EF 5.x).

```
    ///<summary>
    /// Private member mapped in .edmx file
    /// Something like:
    /// <Property Name="jobTitle" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" 
    /// a:SetterAccess="Private" a:GetterAccess="Private" 
    /// xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" />
    ///</summary>
    private string jobTitle { get; set; }
    ///<summary>
    /// Publicly visible property that now contains your logic.
    ///</summary>
    public string JobTitle
    {
        get { return jobTitle; }
        set { jobTitle = SetProperCase(value); }
    }
```

Now when SaveChanges is called it should save the jobTitle property into the column to which it is mapped in your edmx file.